# Riverpod's AsyncValue's when method's properties loading: and error: does not work as official document

Tags: flutter, riverpod, asyncvalue

According to https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncValue-class.html ,
I created the following code;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class User {
  final name = '';
}

final userProvider = StreamProvider<User>((_) async* {
  // fetch the user
});

class Example extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final AsyncValue<User> user = ref.watch(userProvider);

    return user.when(
      loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(), // <---here
      error: (error, stack) => Text('Oops, something unexpected happened'), // <---here
      data: (User user) => Text('Hello ${user.name}'),
    );
  }
}
```

I got the following errors at loading: and error:

**loading:**

> The argument type 'CircularProgressindicator Function()' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(Async Value?)'.
> (Documentation)

**error:**

> The argument type 'Text Function(Object, StackTrace?)' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function (Object, StackTrace?,
> Async Data?)'. (Documentation)

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsvCX.png)

This suddenly happened today. Until yesterday it had been no problem at all.

I am using flutter_riverpod-1.00-dev.11.

I already did "flutter clean", delete pubspec.lock, "flutter pub get".

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you try replacing `WidgetRef ref` with `ScopedReader watch`, I'm testing with `flutter_riverpod: ^0.14.0+3` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation was recently updated because `AsyncValue` was changed on the `master` branch, but the changes aren't published yet.

Since you're using version 1.0.0-dev.11, the syntax is:

```dart
return user.when(
  loading: (_) => CircularProgressIndicator(), // <---here
  error: (error, stack, _) => Text('Oops, something unexpected happened'), // <---here
  data: (User user) => Text('Hello ${user.name}'),
);
```

Those extra parameters were removed recently, so you shouldn't try to use them.